# Centering a widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi I want to center a card which should be centered horizontally and vertically I am trying to acheive this via center widget Any idea how do i accomplish this task

This is what i am getting:

[image]

Here is my  full updated code:

```html
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../BackEnd/AuthenticationService.dart';
import 'Register.dart';

class PatientList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Container(
          height: 174,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
          )),
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                height: 128,
                child: Text(
                  'Patient List',
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      fontSize: 30,
                      color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),

          Center(
            child: Container(
              height: 200,
              child: Card(
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                  side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),
                ),
                child: Center(
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Text("hello@xyz.com",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                      color: Colors.black,
                                      fontSize: 16)),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    context.read<AuthenticationService>().signOut();
                  },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                          side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                        ),
                        primary: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)
                    ),
                    child: Text(' Sign Out'.toUpperCase())
                ),
              ),
            ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
          gotoRegister(BuildContext context) {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Register()),
            );
          }

          gotoRegister(context);
        },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

I want to center that card horizontally and vertically    in the middle of the activity I hope i am now clear with my objectives as to what i want to achieve

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to center the Text inside the card or the card itself? Generally just wrap it with a `Center` widget.

Your problem might be that you use row and column in the wrong place. Please share the complete code, to let me see what needs to be changed.

```
Center(
      child: Container(
        height: 200,
        child: Card(
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
            side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),
          ),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        child: Text("hello@xyz.com",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontSize: 16)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: i want to center the card

Comment: Ok then i suggest you wrap your Card in a Container and give it a height or you use other elements wich share space with the Card. Then just wrap the Container with a Center instead of Positioned and it should work. If you share your complete UI code and not just the card itself it would be easier to know what you want. I updated my original awnser with code which might work.

Answer (score 1):

This should be what you are looking for.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import '../BackEnd/AuthenticationService.dart';
import 'Register.dart';

class PatientList extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 174,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('assets/images/patient_list.png'),
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              height: 128,
              child: Text(
                'Patient List',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 30, color: Colors.white),
              ),
            ),
            Center(
              child: Container(
                height: 200,
                child: Card(
                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                    side: BorderSide(color: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1)),
                  ),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                        child: Row(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              child: Text(
                                "hello@xyz.com",
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            context.read<AuthenticationService>().signOut();
                          },
                          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                            shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                              side: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
                            ),
                            primary: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            ' Sign Out'.toUpperCase(),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Register()),
          );
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(214, 0, 27, 1),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```